# Ways of Baking Animation with Applying Modifiers to Each of the Keyframe?

Tags: animation, modifiers, baking, gltf, three.js

Good day!

**Prehistory:**
I'm creating website which would display different styles of tying shoelaces on 3D shoe mesh.

**Problem I faced with:**
I created and keyframe animated shoelaces using an array and curve modifiers. The problem is, that I would like to export my animated 3D model to the website with glTF file extension, and it doesn't support modifiers.

**Question:**
Is there a way of baking animation with applying modifiers to each of the keyframe without doing this all by myself or are there any other method to animate curve that follows the path?

*P.S. Alembic and Light Point Cache extensions doesn't seem to work for me.*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMxlS.jpg